# Typescript can't find basic types in Angular2 Meteor app

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-meteor

Whenever I use `Date` I get this error on compiling:

> Cannot find name 'Date'

Here's an example of the usage:

```
var pastEvents = Events.find({ timestamp: { $lt: new Date() }});
```

**Notes:**

- Same thing happens with
- This is a Angular2 Meteor app
- I am not importing anything at the top, so if I need to, that'll be the issue.
- Same thing happens with `string`, `number`, and any other basic types.

I can list typings, my tsconfig.json file, or any other information you need. Just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install your typings correctly?

```
$ sudo npm install typings -g
$ typings init
$ typings install es6-promise --save
$ typings install dt~es6-shim --global --save
$ typings install registry:env/meteor --global
```

Since even the standard types give errors you might want to compare your tsconfig and other settings with this angular2-meteor base app:
https://github.com/bsliran/angular2-meteor-base